# Compute $P(A|B,C)$ knowing only $P(A|B)$ and $P(A|C)$

Tags: probability

This is perhaps better explained with an example.

Say we have 2 models:

- Model 1 takes a name, and outputs a probability whether it is a female name or male name. ie. $P(gender | name)$
- Model 2 takes an audio recording of speech, and outputs a probability whether it belongs to a woman or a man. ie. $P(gender | speech)$

Also assume that it's not trivial to compute marginals $P(gender)$, $P(name)$, and $P(speech)$.

I would like to compute $P(gender | name, speech)$. I want to use both signals to give me a better guess. How do I compute it from the two conditional distributions above?

(Intuitively, it seems like it should be a weighted combination of $P(gender | name)$ and  $P(gender | speech)$. However, I can't figure out what this weight should be.)

Comment: You can't do it, unfortunately, except in special cases.  Consider, as a simple example, $A=B*C$, where $B$ and $C$ are distributed uniformly on $(0,1)$.  $P(A|B)$ is uniform over $(0,B)$, and similarly for $P(A|C)$, but there's no way to combine the two distributions to get $P(A|B,C)$ without knowing that $A=B*C$, which of course immediately gives you $P(A|B,C)$ w/o having to work with $P(A|B)$ and $P(A|C)$ at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a strictly probabilistic perspective, that weight will depend on how much overlap there is between name and speech pattern variables, so there is not one right answer.

$P(gender|name,speech)$ can be equal to $P(gender|name)$ if speech pattern did not tell us anything about gender that name did not already tell us (in other words, if we took a name, all individuals with that name had the same speech pattern).  (And similarly with $P(gender|name,speech)$ equating to $P(gender|speech)$).

If, however, every instance of a particular name was associated with a different speech pattern and with a different gender, then it is possible for $P(gender|name,speech)$ to equal to $P(gender|name) + P(gender|speech)$ or to $P(gender|name) - P(gender|speech)$.

Having said all that, you may want to try ensemble methods / model stacking to try to get better predictions from your separate models.  It can be as simple as taking a simple average of predictions from different models, but it can also involve implementing  second-level (and higher order) prediction models using predictions from the original models as input.